# Passing JSON Arrays with Async Waterfall

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, asynchronous

I'm somewhat new to NodeJS and async operations so forgive me if I'm making obvious mistakes here.

I'm attempting to loop through a series of Excel cells, ping a series of APIs with their respective values, and aggregate them into the conData object which I will push to an array.

My question is this- how do I concatenate JSON into one array and send it to my client?

```
router.post('/load', multipartMiddleware, function (req, res, next) {

async.waterfall([
    function (done) {
        var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
        workbook.xlsx.readFile(req.files.file.path)


        .then(function() {

            var worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet(1)
            var colH = worksheet.getColumn(8)
            var dataArray = []

            colH.eachCell(function(cell, rowNumber) {

                var conNoteNumber = cell.value

                starTrack.getGuid(conNoteNumber, function (guid) {

                    starTrack.getConEvents(guid[0], function (events) {

                    var last =  _.last(events)

                        starTrack.getConSummary(guid[0], function (summary) {

                            var conData = {
                                rowNum: rowNumber,
                                conNum: conNoteNumber,
                                date: last['EventDate'],
                                time: last['Time'],
                                location: last['Location'],
                                status: last['Status'],
                                time: last['Time'],
                                summary: summary['StatusDescription']
                            }
                            dataArray.push(conData)      
                            done(null, dataArray)
                        })
                    })
                })
            })
        })
    }

], function done(err, dataArray) {
    // console.log(bundle)
    if (err) return next(err);
    // console.log(dataArray)
    res.end()

 })
```

Comment: Could you clarify the question? The code you've posted seems to do basically the right thing. What is it doing that you don't want, or what is it not doing that you do want?

Comment: Thanks Chris - essentially in the colH.eachCell I'm looping through each row and making a series of API calls - the conData object at the point where it is created represents essentially 1 unit. 
Even though I push my conData json objects to the dataArray, when I console log it in my final async operation, I'm only getting one object.

Comment: Ah - so your issue is really knowing when all the api calls you make in that loop are done so you can pass out the final aggregated result in `dataArray`?

Comment: Exactly ... What I think I've done is stopped the operation at the first push but when I move my callback further down I don't have access to the dataArray in that scope

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea about using waterfall. I highly recommend you to read the async documentation because there are other collections and control flow functions you need to use in this code. 
I don't have an opportunity to test my answer but I'm hoping to give you an idea:

```
async.waterfall([
    function (done) {
        var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
        workbook.xlsx.readFile(req.files.file.path)
      },
      function(err, workbook){
        var worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet(1)
        var colH = worksheet.getColumn(8)
        var dataArray = []

        async.map(colH.eachCell, function(cell, rowNumber){
          var conNoteNumber = cell.value;
          async.waterfall([
            starTrack.getGuid(conNoteNumber),
            function(err, guid){
                starTrack.getConEvents(guid[0])
                cb(guid[0]);
            },
            function(err, summary){
              var conData = {
                  rowNum: rowNumber,
                  conNum: conNoteNumber,
                  date: last['EventDate'],
                  time: last['Time'],
                  location: last['Location'],
                  status: last['Status'],
                  time: last['Time'],
                  summary: summary['StatusDescription']
              }
              dataArray.push(conData);
              done(null, dataArray);
            }
          ])
        });
      }

], function done(err, dataArray) {
    // console.log(bundle)
    if (err) return next(err);
    // console.log(dataArray)
    res.end()

 })
```

You can see, in the second method of the waterfall array, I call .map function to apply a function to every element(cell) of a collection(colH). There are slight differences between .map and .each in async library. Make sure to read both and decide which one you need.

In async.map, I used another async.waterfall. As you might know, async waterfall, automatically passes the result of the function as argument to the next function.

I hope this helps, if you have more questions, please comment. I had pretty tough time with async library couple months ago and the best advice I can give is read the documentation ([here](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall)) carefully.

Comment: Melis - first off thanks very much.  I'm definitely missing some of the more intricate control flows of this library so I'll definitely read the docs.  I'm incorporating your suggestions now and will keep you updated with progress.